# Android Shared Preferences Demo

Tags: android

create file with bellow name

how to use

public class AppPreferences

{

```
public static final String PREF_NAME = "XYZ";

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public static final int MODE = Context.MODE_PRIVATE;

 public static final String ISLOGIN = "islogin";

public static void writeBoolean(Context context, String key, boolean value)
{
    getEditor(context).putBoolean(key, value).commit();
}

public static boolean readBoolean(Context context, String key,
                                  boolean defValue) {
    return getPreferences(context).getBoolean(key, defValue);
}

public static void writeInteger(Context context, String key, int value) {
    getEditor(context).putInt(key, value).commit();

}

public static int readInteger(Context context, String key, int defValue) {
    return getPreferences(context).getInt(key, defValue);
}

public static void writeString(Context context, String key, String value) {
    getEditor(context).putString(key, value).commit();

}

public static String readString(Context context, String key, String defValue) {
    return getPreferences(context).getString(key, defValue);
}

public static void writeFloat(Context context, String key, float value) {
    getEditor(context).putFloat(key, value).commit();
}

public static float readFloat(Context context, String key, float defValue) {
    return getPreferences(context).getFloat(key, defValue);
}

public static void writeLong(Context context, String key, long value) {
    getEditor(context).putLong(key, value).commit();
}

public static long readLong(Context context, String key, long defValue) {
    return getPreferences(context).getLong(key, defValue);
}

public static SharedPreferences getPreferences(Context context) {
    return context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, MODE);
}

public static SharedPreferences.Editor getEditor(Context context) {
    return getPreferences(context).edit();
}
```

}

how to use :

1) Get Data:
 boolean islogin = AppPreferences.readBoolean(Splash_screen.this,AppPreferences.ISLOGIN,false);

2) Put Data :
AppPreferences.writeBoolean(LoginActivity.this,AppPreferences.ISLOGIN,true);

Comment: and the question is?

Comment: whats the question? That seems like the way to use...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should work fine ,would you explain whats the problem

Comment: how to post my documentation for this

Comment: if you like to add a javadoc just  type /** before the method declaration and press the enter , then javadoc generated automatically you can read more in https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/15.0/viewing-inline-documentation.html